# IPhone Settings screen and images

Tags: iphone, image, settings, plist, root.plist

I want to implement a settings screen on the iPhone with images and hyperlinks, like the one for the twitter settings in the standard settings.

I can specify textfields and titles, but i cannot seem to incorporate hyperlinks and images into them. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanx in advance!

John.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add some image or url to your bundle settings (at least the conventional way).

Here's is a list of what is available :
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Twitter app does not have an external setting bundle (= settings from the general settings menu) but an in-app settings controller. Of course, with an in-app controller, you can have a nicer control of your views and have some dynamic entries.

**EDIT :**

From iOS 5, Twitter app is a native application. It setting entry is in the second section of general setting menu (not in the third one, as other app). Like iPod, Safari or Photos, for example. Obviously, native applications can make a lot more stuff than our poor appstore applications, like controlling the system, or display images, links and webviews in settings.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, however, my iPhone (4) has twitter settings and does show an icon and company name in the general settings app. The simulator even shows a hyperlink in the general settings app.

Comment: Aaah, okay ! I'm currently on iOS 4, and my iPhone does not have the build-in Twitter app. See my edit